# The Revolution Badge doesn't work now that there's a "Commit" phase

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, badges

The Revolution Badge currently requires 100 *followers* for a user's proposal.

But a sucessful site will move into the commitment phase with fewer than 100 followers.   (Only 60 are required once the on-topic and off-topic questions have been defined.)

We surely don't intend to award a badge only for proposals that have such poorly defined "on-topic" and "off-topic" questions that they fail to move into commitment until after they have 100 followers.

**It should be changed to require 100 total *followers or committers*, or possibly, 100 total *followers, commiters, or beta users*.**

Presumably, given the higher level of accountability (real name, email), a commiter is *more* valuable than a follower, anyway.  And a beta user is clearly more valuable.

Comment: it's just a subtle reminder that nobody can overthrow Jeff 'n' Joel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We changed the Revolution badge to be awarded to creators of proposals with >=100 followers *or >= committers*.

As a result, the creators of [three](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/homebrewing-beer-wine-etc) [additional](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games) [proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15894/visual-studio-alm) just earned the Revolution badge. (i.e. Alright, Jaydles, you have your second Revolution now, so quit showing off!)

Comment: I never said the request wasn't self-serving...